# AsyncTask - use it or not?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I create adding product to shopping cart process in Android. The process probably will be:

- run `web service` to take product details.
- choose quantity and add product to product list (`web service`).
- update screen product list (take new list from `web service`)

Is there any sense to use here `AsyncTask` class? Seems that `single thread` is even better for me (user will not obtain information earlier than result from `web service`).
Am I right?

Comment: it depends on your requirement. if you need that "details" to be read by customer, then dont use asynctask

Comment: if you not use AsyncTask for getData from webservice you get NetworkThread Exception..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would be using the `AsyncTask` anyway, as almost all android http-frameworks are using it.

What you mean with a single thread is correct, unless this thread is NOT the `MainThread` :). Android throws an exception immediately as soon as you try to block the main thread somehow.

So, the AsyncTask(+) is your only option to encapsulate the http-processing in your app

Comment: I cannot execute any DefaultHttpClient() connection without encapsulating it in AsyncTask class? :)

Comment: in a background service you should be able to do it, but not in an activity

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is must when you're using webservice

here its a example link for Ksoap webservice in Android 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242

Ksoap with AsyncTask

[Android, AsyncTask with kSoap2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388983/android-asynctask-with-ksoap2?rq=1)